# Declare Dynamic Array in main, malloc and initialize in function, print array in main

Tags: c, arrays

I'm declaring a pointer in main.  I then allocating memory and initialize values inside a function, then return to main and print the data.  For some reason when I allocate, initialize, and print in func1 it works.  Once  and I leave the func though I seg fault.  I've googled this problem and search for about 2 hours on this site.  I'm stuck.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int func1(int *array);

int main() {

    int *array;
    func1(array);
    printf("Main: %d\n", array[1]);
    return 0;

}

int func1(int *array) {

    array = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    printf("Enter an int: ");
    scanf("%d", &array[1]);
    printf("Func1: %d\n", array[1]);
}
```

This is what my command line looks like:

```
Enter an int: 5
Func1: 5
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First a word about terminology, your variable `array` is technically not an array, it's a pointer. It can be made to point to memory that can be used as an array though.

Now for your problem: It's that when you pass arguments to functions those are passed *by value*, meaning they are copied. So in the function `func1` the argument `array` is just a copy, and changing a copy will not change the original. Since the original is not changed, you will then in the `main` function dereference an uninitialized pointer, leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and the crash.

To solve this you have to emulate *pass by reference*. This is done by passing the argument using a pointer. In this case you have to pass a pointer to the pointer.

First you of course need to change the function:

```
void func1(int **array) {

    *array = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    printf("Enter an int: ");
    scanf("%d", &(*array)[1]);
    printf("Func1: %d\n", (*array)[1]);
}
```

Then you need to use the address-of operator `&` when calling the function

```
int *array;
func1(&array);
```

An important note: The `malloc` function does not initialize the memory it allocates, which means that the contents of the memory is *indeterminate*. Only the second `int` element of the allocated memory is initialized and can be properly referenced, reading all other elements will also lead to undefined behavior.

---

Another thing, that also leads to *undefined behavior*, and as noted by Namfuak, is that in your original function `func1` you declared it as returning an integer, but you don't actually return anything. That's why I changed the function here in my answer to return `void`.

Comment: __pass by reference__ is not allowed in `C`

Comment: @Learner That's why I say *emulate* pass by reference.

Comment: Sorry I missed that part..

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that `func1` is supposed to return an `int` but doesn't return anything.